# Caculating coordinates of specific point on the line

Tags: java, android, algorithm, math, geometry

So, I hope this still classifies as coding, not math... Oh well, aren't they same anyway ;) 
So, my problem is this: I would want to calculate coordinates of a point on line.

For example, if I had point A(0, 0) and point B(5, -3), I'd like to calculate coordinates of point C, witch is 2 (can also be something else than 2) from A and on the line AB. I hope 
you realized what I mean.

I know how to calculate distance between A and B, but locating C.. I literally don't know where to start. And even less on how to implement int in java. Some help for newbie?

Comment: There are two points on *line* AB that are within a distance `d` from `A`. Do you need both of them? Maybe you meant a segment (and then there could be zero points, if |AB|<d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more mathematical approach: (I hope you understand my drawing)

[image]

You know A and B and the distance from A to C. The angle can be calculated by calculatin the slope of [AB]. From here you should be able to figure the lenght of the 2 segments (marked with blue), by using sin and cos.

Comment: That really seems what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Use the parametric equation of the line: `P = (1-t).A + t.B` (`P`, `A`, and `B` are points, defined by pairs of coordinates). If you set `t=0`, you get `A`; if you set `t=1`, you get `B`; if you set other values, you get points along the line `AB`.

Now the distance issue: you want `P` to be at distance `d` of `A`. Then `d² = AP² = t²AB²`, or `t = d/AB`.

Programmatically:

```
ABx= Bx - Ax; 
ABy= By - Ay;
AB= Sqrt(ABx * ABx + ABy * ABy);

t= d / AB;

Xc= Xa + t * ABx;
Yc= Ya + t * ABy;
```